# Постраничный вывод данных

Tags: java, база-данных

Добрый день, сделал простенькую пагинацию для своего проекта, хотел сделать чтобы выводилось хотя бы по 5 страниц (сделал это с помощью цыкла for в скриплете), может кто подскажет в чем проблема и как ее решить, первая страница выводится нормально, а вот вторая уже не полностью, и странички не хочет показывать на первой странице.

**Сервлет**

```
public class SkisqlController extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/skisql.jsp";
private static String LIST_SKISQL = "/listSkisql.jsp";
private SkisqlDao dao;

public SkisqlController() {
    super();
    dao = new SkisqlDao();
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    String forward = "";
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
        String kiz = (request.getParameter("kiz"));
        dao.deleteSkisql(kiz); 
        forward = LIST_SKISQL;
        request.setAttribute("skisqls", dao.getAllSkisqls(1));
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")) {
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
        String kiz = (request.getParameter("kiz"));
        Skisql skisql = dao.getSkisqlByKiz(kiz);
        request.setAttribute("skisql", skisql);
    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listSkisql")) {
        forward = LIST_SKISQL;
        request.setAttribute("skisqls", dao.getAllSkisqls(1));
        request.setAttribute("page", 1);
    } else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
        String page = (request.getParameter("page"));
        forward = LIST_SKISQL;
        request.setAttribute("skisqls", dao.getAllSkisqls(Integer.parseInt(page)));
        request.setAttribute("page", page);

    }
    else {
        forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
    }

    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
}
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
```

**И сама jsp страница куда вывожу данные**

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <style>
            <%@include file='css/table.css' %>
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <%int paged = (int) request.getAttribute("page");%>
        <div id="pagination">
            <ul class="pag">
                <li><a class="a2" href=SkisqlController?action=list&page=${page-1}>Назад</a></li>
                    <%
                        for (int i = paged - 2; i <= paged + 2; i++) {
                    %>

                <li><a class="a2" href=SkisqlController?action=list&page=${i}>${i}</a></li>

                    <%
                        }
                    %>

                <li><a class="a2" href=SkisqlController?action=list&page=${page+1}>Вперед</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Укажите какая используется СУБД. Еще, Вы можете определить на какой стадии возникает ошибка? Например: если сам запрос напрямую к БД не работает, то можно оставить только его; если запрос работает, но `resultSet` в `DAO` возвращает не все данные, то можно оставить только `DAO` и т.д.

Comment: СУБД postgresql, сам запрос работает, так как на первой странице выводится первые 100 записей с таблицы

Comment: В общем почитайте [как создать минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) у Вас в вопросе много кода, который не имеет отношения к проблеме.

Comment: Проверьте какие значения подставляются в запрос в `DAO` для второй страницы. Составьте запрос и проверьте его через базу. Если работает, проверяйте какие записи попадают в `DAO`. Если в `DAO` все нормально проверяйте сервлет. В общем локализуйте проблему.

Comment: ну вот получается если с jsp страницы убрать скриплеты с кодом, то по всем страницам можно спокойно проходить, все выводиться правильно, я хотел сделать что бы отображалось n-е количество страниц, а не только вперед назад, хотя бы 5 штук, вот это я пытался сделать кодом в скриплетах, отладка показывает что при переходе на вторую страницу  курсор попадает в эту строку ( <%int paged = (int) request.getAttribute("page");%>) и сразу прыгает за тег </html>

Comment: 1. Возьмите значение `href` в кавычки. 2. Замените `${page-1}` на `${paged-1}` и аналогично в двух других ссылках. 3. Ссылка какая-то странная. У вас URL так и называется `SkisqlController`?

Comment: Спасибо за советы, завтра или послезавтра попробую сделать и отпишусь, а то у нас на роботе ремонт, и доступа к пк нет, ссылка выглядит в адресной строке так SkisqlController?action=list&page=, и после равно номер соответствующей страницы

Comment: Заменил `${page-1}` на `${paged-1}` не помогло, так же на второй странице данные выводятся не полностью, если взять значение href в кавычки выдается вот такая вот ошибка: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Займитесь отладкой сервлета. Выведите в логи: 1) какое значение принял параметр `page`; 2) сколько записей вернулось из `DAO` проверьте данные на второй странице. Нужно точно узнать где ошибка:  в JSP, в сервлете или глубже.

Comment: ну так как первая страница отрабатывает нормально, и без скриплетов открываются все страницы, скорее всего проблема вот в этой строчке `<%int paged = (int) request.getAttribute("page");%>` возможно я как-то не правильно передаю параметр, просто в яве я не так давно, когда прохожу отладкой, оно с этой строчки прыгает сразу за тег `</html>`.

Comment: попытался вывести значение `<li>${paged}</li>` ничего не вывело, выводит только в таком виде `<li>${page}</li>`, значит в переменную `paged`ничего не передает

Comment: Уже третий день непонятно, что происходит. Дополните вопрос (кнопкой «править») наиболее полной информацией по ошибке. Покажите скриншоты первой и второй страницы (залейте изображения на imgur.com и вставьте ссылки если репутация не позволяет вставлять картинки напрямую). Укажите что именно не так на второй странице. Укажите точно какая ветка `if` исполняется в коде и какие значения принимают все переменные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хоть и нет полной информации по ошибке, подозреваю, что проблема связана с некорректным преобразованием типов.

Вы передаете атрибут как строку:

```
String page = (request.getParameter("page"));
...
request.setAttribute("page", page);
```

, а обрабатываете его как число:

```
<%int paged = (int) request.getAttribute("page");%>
```

Что, скорее всего приводит к ошибке преобразования типов.

На первой странице атрибут передается как число и ошибки не происходит.

```
request.setAttribute("page", 1);
```

Попробуйте преобразовывать значение в число:

```
String page = (request.getParameter("page"));
forward = LIST_SKISQL;
int pageValue = Integer.parseInt(page);
request.setAttribute("skisqls", dao.getAllSkisqls(pageValue));
request.setAttribute("page", pageValue);
```

Далее, чтобы вывести переменную `i` вам понадобится синтаксис скриплета (`<%=i%>` вместо `${i}`):

```
<li><a class="a2" href=SkisqlController?action=list&page=<%=i%>><%=i%></a></li>
```

Comment: В контроллере я ничего не менял просто в скриплете сделал, так `for (int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) - 2; 
                                i <= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page")) + 2; 
                                i++) {`
 а вот про это `<%=i%>` я не знал, спасибо большое))

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Пожалуйста, тогда лучше инициализацию поменять: `int paged = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));`

Comment: а я инициализацию убрал, я теперь переменную страници с контроллера передаю